# php sha1 does not match .Net sha1Managed

Tags: c#, php, sha1, mismatch

I am having problem in matching a SHA1 algorithm in PHP and C# .Net. I need to modify the PHP code to match with .Net value.

The code in .Net is as following:

```
DateTime dtNow = DateTime.parse("4/29/2013 11:50:18 PM");
//Create the site token header
var siteTokenMessageHeader = new SiteTokenMessageHeader
{
    MessageId = "0289ED53-D69B-451C-BCBB-C7412D07AFFE",
    //Unquie Id per message, use for auditing
    TimeStamp = dtNow,
    //Current Time
    SiteId = _siteId,
};
//Construct Token 
var token = string.Format(
    "{0}:\"MessageId\":\"{1}\"\"SiteId\":\"{2}\"\"TimeStamp\":\"{3}\"",
    _siteKey,
    siteTokenMessageHeader.MessageId,
    siteTokenMessageHeader.SiteId,
    siteTokenMessageHeader.TimeStamp.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US"))); //1/1/2000 12:00:00 AM
//Construct signature from token
var shaProvider = new SHA1Managed();
var rawKey = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(token);
var rawHash = shaProvider.ComputeHash(rawKey);
var signature = BitConverter.ToString(rawHash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();

siteTokenMessageHeader.SiteSignature = signature;
```

The signature variable value: 8cf9000e9b1a6da0e898bada5bf6dd8f6d17d72a

The PHP code is as following:

```
$str = $SiteKey.':"MessageId":"0289ED53-D69B-451C-BCBB-C7412D07AFFE""SiteId":"'.$SiteId.'""TimeStamp":"4/29/2013 11:50:18 AM"';
$hash = sha1($str);
```

The $hash variable value: 1d2fb85fd63a14de0b5e0a95be253eac1a625128

The same topic has been answered quite a few times but none of those are helpful in this case.
Anybody's help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

See here its `AM` in `PHP`

```
""TimeStamp":"4/29/2013 11:50:18 AM"'
                                 ^^
```

And `PM` in `C#`

```
parse("4/29/2013 11:50:18 PM");
                          ^^
```

Because of this ,different result is coming.

Make both as `AM` OR `PM`, you will get same hash.

Comment: Thanks much for pointing it out. Actually I have wrote it wrongly. I am using "AM" in both the cases.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues:

1. As @Yogesh notes, the string is different (`AM` vs. `PM`)
2. The C# code uses UTF-16, the php code ASCII or some legacy encoding
3. Your MAC construction is broken. SHA-1(key||message) is vulnerable to length extension attacks.

Since the code is broken, you need to change it on both sides. I recommend switching to `HMAC-SHA-2` with a UTF-8 encoded message.

Comment: Thanks but in order to use HMAC-SHA2 I will require a secret key which is not provided. Thats why I am unable to use HMAC.
I have tried:
    $str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'utf-8');
    echo $hash = sha1($str);
but its giving the same value as without encoding.

Comment: You're using something called `SiteKey`. This should not be a prefix of the message, but rather a proper MAC key. The C# code sucks, don't reproduce it. Fix it. Why do use crypto if you don't use it securely?

Comment: You'd get the same results as your current C# code if you use `utf-16` in php.

Comment: Thanks again for your efforts!
but here the C# code is able to connect to the remote server, which means it is producing same as the server, and that is required. Also tried convert encoding to UTF-16 but alas, no luck!